# AG-Grid - dropdown list with collective selection while using rowGrouping

Tags: javascript, angular, ag-grid

I'm using AG-Grid to generate a table with Groups & Checkbox selection.
What I want to do, is defining one of the 'root' fields, as a drop-down list field, so when selected, the value will be set for all of the children.

[image]

As you can see below, the drop-down list is available for every child, but I can't make it available **at the root level as well.**, probably because of the grouping :

[image]

So basically, I have 2 questions :

- How can I display the same drop-down list, at the **top level**, along with the "Hostname" field ?
- How can I do, so when the **root level checkbox** is selected, then all children drop-down values will be modified with the 'drop-down root selected' value?

  ```
  generateGroupSelectionGridConfig(aggrField: string, userAvailableForms: string[], defaultFields: string[], allFields: Array<any>) {

    let gridOptions : GridOptions = {
        columnDefs: [],
        pagination: true,
        rowSelection: 'multiple',
    };

    //Looping through each one of the fields
    allFields.forEach( colField => {

        let fieldValue = colField.COLUMN_NAME;

        gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
            field : fieldValue,
            rowGroup: fieldValue == aggrField ? true : false,
            hide: defaultFields.indexOf(fieldValue) !== -1 && fieldValue !== aggrField ? false : true,
            maxWidth: 220,
            aggFunc: 'sum'
        });

    });


    gridOptions.columnDefs.push({
        field: "Form",
        editable:true,
        cellEditor: 'agSelectCellEditor',
        cellRenderer: params => {return params.value ? params.value : 'Click to Select Form';},
        cellEditorParams: {
            values: userAvailableForms
        }
    });

    gridOptions.defaultColDef = {
        flex: 1,
        minWidth: 100
    };


    gridOptions.autoGroupColumnDef = {
        headerName: aggrField.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + aggrField.slice(1),
        field: aggrField,
        maxWidth: 160,
        cellRenderer: 'agGroupCellRenderer',
        cellRendererParams: {
            checkbox: true,
        }
    };


    return gridOptions;
  }
  ```